# Woocommerce add custom email notify

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I try add custom notify using this tutorial https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/.

I hooked on 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', but my trigger method not work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed',  array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
```

I try use this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50738/why-do-some-hooks-not-work-inside-class-context, but it not work for my.

Comment: Please post your trigger function code.

Comment: For test I use this simple code:

   `public function trigger( $order_id ) {

        file_put_contents('test-email.txt', $order_id . " " . time() . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}`